# Who can explain this code ? Why it shows 1

Tags: c++, c++11

How does this work?

```
int a=5<=5;
cout<<a; // output : 1
```

Who can explain why output is 1?

Comment: Its plain simple. What you didn't understand ? See [Two-way comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison)

Comment: Were you expecting something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because

1. `<=` has higher priority than `=` so it is calculated first.
2. `5 <= 5` returns a boolean, which is true.
3. It is converted into an integer, which is 1.
4. then 1 is assigned to `a`.

so `a` equals 1 now.

Answer (score 0):

`5<=5` is `true` which, when converted to an integer is `1`.

You assign this value to `a` which then holds the value `1`. Which you then output.

You may want to read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence